# R web-scraping - hidden text in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, r, web-scraping

I want to scrape the urls from the following page:

http://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/1186/seeall.html?type=CRE&leg=5

There are 180 urls to be collected from this page (each is a link to a speech given in Parliament), but I am running into problems whenever there are more than 100 urls to be scraped, as the additional speeches are only accessible by clicking on the "See More" box at the bottom of the page. I've tried to figure out how to reveal the additional links that I think are hidden by the "getMore" function, but with no luck! Apologies for naiveté here...

My current code is as follows:

### Read in the page

```
mep.speech.list.url <-"http://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/1186/seeall.html?type=CRE&leg=5"
speech.list.data<-try(readLines(mep.speech.list.url),silent=TRUE)
```

### Find urls

```
mep.speech.list<-speech.list.data
mep.speech.lines<-grep("href",mep.speech.list)
mep.speech.list<-mep.speech.list[mep.speech.lines]
mep.speech.lines<-grep("target",mep.speech.list)
mep.speech.list<-mep.speech.list[mep.speech.lines]
mep.speech.list<-mep.speech.list[-length(mep.speech.list)]
```

### Clean URLs

```
mep.speech.list.end<-regexpr("target",mep.speech.list)
mep.speech.list<-substr(mep.speech.list,1, mep.speech.list.end)
mep.speech.list<-gsub("\t","",mep.speech.list)
mep.speech.list<-gsub('<a href=\"',"",mep.speech.list)
mep.speech.list<-gsub('\" target',"",mep.speech.list)
mep.speech.list<-gsub('\" targe',"",mep.speech.list)    
mep.speech.list<-gsub('\" targ',"",mep.speech.list)
mep.speech.list<-gsub('\" tar',"",mep.speech.list)
mep.speech.list<-gsub('\" ta',"",mep.speech.list)
mep.speech.list<-gsub('\" t',"",mep.speech.list)    
mep.speech.list<-mep.speech.list[5:length(mep.speech.list)]
print(mep.speech.list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SEE MORE button executes some javascript that carries out an AJAX call. You can use Selenium to
automate the browser and extract the links:

```
require(RSelenium)
appURL <- "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/meps/en/1186/seeall.html?type=CRE&leg=5"
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(appURL)
remDr$findElement("id", "seemore")$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(5)
jsScript <-"var hrefs = new Array();
$('#content_left .listcontent a').each(function(){
hrefs.push($(this).attr('href'));
});
return hrefs;"

appHREF <- remDr$executeScript(jsScript)[[1]]
> head(appHREF)
[1] "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT+CRE+20040504+ITEM-008+DOC+XML+V0//EN&language=en&query=INTERV&detail=2-205"
[2] "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT+CRE+20040422+ITEM-005+DOC+XML+V0//EN&language=en&query=INTERV&detail=4-069"
[3] "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT+CRE+20040422+ITEM-005+DOC+XML+V0//EN&language=en&query=INTERV&detail=4-122"
[4] "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT+CRE+20040421+ITEM-008+DOC+XML+V0//EN&language=en&query=INTERV&detail=3-207"
[5] "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT+CRE+20040330+ITEM-004+DOC+XML+V0//EN&language=en&query=INTERV&detail=2-074"
[6] "http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT+CRE+20040330+ITEM-004+DOC+XML+V0//EN&language=en&query=INTERV&detail=2-099"
>
```

Comment: This is perfect, and much appreciated. Looks like I have some more reading to do about Selenium...

Comment: One quick follow up, if you don't mind: I'm trying to run this on an EC2 server as set-up here:[link](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/). I'm struggling to get the remote driver to open on the AMI and am getting this error: `Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed connect to localhost:4444; Connection refused`. Any idea how to do this? Many thanks.

Comment: It may be easier in that case to use a headless browser like phantomjs. The RSelenium package contains a vignette on using phantomjs. Really all that is needed is that the phantomjs binary is in your path then the selenium server will find it. `remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs')` would launch the required browser.

Comment: Alternatively you can look at http://mike.ucoz.com/publ/programming/ubuntu/selenium_ubuntu_amazon_ec2_headless/8-1-0-4